# IE7 background issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Currently having this really odd problem with my layout IE7. I'm not very experienced at handling IE7's bugs, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

If you look quickly soon after the page has loaded in IE7, the background isn't covering the whole content. Sometimes it gets stuck at the top, most of the time it covers all the content except the footer. Again, sometimes it decides to (after a few seconds) finally jump from not covering the footer to covering all the content like it should. As far as I'm aware, I've put the clearfix's where they should be. I've also tried using "overflow: auto" instead, but no luck.

Can anyone help me out? Check out the site here:

http://www.matthewruddy.com/demo/

Some of the scripts:

The source: http://pastebin.com/r6R2rdP6

The CSS: http://pastebin.com/qtMa22xX

The issues appear to be concerning #body, #page, #content, #bottom-sidebar, etc.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help; Matthew.

Comment: That's a really cool site! Maybe something like `clear:both` could solve it, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: As I said above, clear: both (clearfix is what I called it above) hasn't fixed the issue in IE7.

Comment: There is a lot of `position: relative` & `zoom: 1`'s throughout you're inline CSS. It maybe a quirk of how IE renders/handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.matthewruddy.com/demo/wp-content/themes/la-rivista/lib/scripts/jquery.border.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// IE rounded borders
DD_roundies.addRule('#body', '5px');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

from inside your `<head>` tag to just before your closing body tag (`</body>`) sorts it out.

There might be a better way.

Comment: Wow.. Never would have thought that script would be causing the issue. Can I ask, how did you figure this out? Any sort of tool?

Comment: How I figured it out: I used IE's "Developer Tools" to apply a few general float clearing styles, because that would've been the easiest fix. That didn't work (but adding/removing any style "fixed" the problem = "reflow/repaint" issue), so I copied your source code, and added this at the top of your `<head>` tag: `<base href="http://www.matthewruddy.com/demo/" />` - this fixes all the file paths in the document to load from your site. Then, I noticed you were using DD_roundies. I temporarily removed the script, and it was fixed. So, I figured moving that to the bottom would fix it, and it did.